# Screen froze with weird rectangles and sounds loops the last few milliseconds while running PopOS 22.04

Tags: audio, video, bug, pop-os

What happens is the computer (Dell Inspiron 14) works normally running PopOS 22.04 as expected.

And then suddenly, this odd bug happens: The screen froze with weird rectangles and sounds loops for the last few milliseconds. Screenshot below.

Does anyone know the root of this bug and perhaps a way to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Classic symptom of "overheat or under-power" causing the GPU to freak out, which also causes the sound to 'micro-loop'… the trouble is trying to identify which:\ I've seen this on several machines, most were a failing or under-spec PSU, one was a dying graphics card. To this day I don't know how to identify which is the cause, except to replace parts until it stops crashing.

Comment: Or a driver issue. Had this on a computer, driver crashed, produced this problem, a reboot later, GPU driver could not load, resulting in 640x480x16 color mode. Rebooting to save mode, installing driver, and all was fine ever since.

Comment: Also, could be a PopOS bug.

Comment: It is the repeating of the sound that makes me come to this conclusion.  There is a filled sound buffer and an interrupt saying "I am done" and nothing is picking it up.  Of course a guess.

Comment: Interesting, I managed to reproduce the error, and the computer was hot when the bug happened; what you said, guys, makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

### These are classic signs of a machine — or GPU specifically — overheating.

Based on what you describe, this seems to be a case of the PC overheating. So either the PC is defective — fans not working as expected — or the OS is not handling overheating conditions well.

#### Update the PC’s drivers.

In the case of the OS not handling overheating conditions well, this could be tied to a driver issue with the GPU where fans don’t kick in when the GPU overheats. Or just the OS itself is doing a bad job of regulating temperature.

So your best bet is to update drivers for the GPU. And if there is any option in the OS to change when the fans kick in, look at that and adjust them so the fans kick in at a slightly lower temperature and see if that helps.

#### Clean out dust in the PC.

Another idea, if you feel up to it, is to open up the case and use a can of compressed air to clean out the fans — and the case itself — of any/all dust present. If there isn’t decent airflow the fans might be spinning but the air is not flowing as it should and not cooling off the system as desired.

But as I said, only do this if you feel up to it. Some people just are not up to opening a case or are — to be blunt — a bit clumsy so opening up a case might cause a risk of damage. Only do that if you are up to it. And if not? Maybe get a professional repair shop to clean it up for you.

Comment: checking for it, thank you very much